# Can you restrict a generic to T where T is a trait implemented by Self?

Tags: rust

For example, is there some way of doing this:

```
use std::marker::PhantomFn;

trait Valid : PhantomFn<Self>  {}
trait Invalid : PhantomFn<Self>  {}

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn as_trait<T: ?Sized>(&self) -> &T where Self: T {
        return self as &T;
    }
}

impl Valid for Foo {}

fn main() {
  let foo = Foo;

  // Should return a trait reference &Valid
  let _ = foo.as_trait::<Valid>();

  // Should fail to compile because Invalid is not implemented for Foo
  let _ = foo.as_trait::<Invalid>(); 
}
```

i.e. restrict a generic to be only for traits where the trait is implemented on Self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to be generic over traits right now (and I haven't heard any plans to make it so), so `Foo: T` with a generic `T` will not be valid.

When you use a trait name in a position where a type is expected, it's treated as a trait object type rather than a trait. Thus, `foo.as_trait::<Valid>()` instantiates the type variable `T` as the trait object type `Valid` (which is allowed since you specified `?Sized`). Then, in `Self: T`, `T` is a type rather than a trait, so it's the wrong kind of thing.

The compiler will tell you the same thing in fewer words:

```
<anon>:9:53: 9:54 error: `T` is not a trait
<anon>:9     fn as_trait<T: ?Sized>(&self) -> &T where Self: T {
                                                             ^
```