# Is there any way cast to a generic T, where T is an arbitrary trait type?

Tags: rust

My question title is a little vague, but in essence I want to achieve the following:

- struct Foo implements BehaviourA and BehaviourB and BehaviourC
- struct Bar implements BehaviourA
- Both Foo and Bar implement some Content trait
- From a `&Content` get a reference to a behaviour, if it is implemented.

This is broadly speaking possible by forcing `Content` to know explicitly about `BehaviourA`, etc. like:

```
fn as_a(&self) -> Option<&BehaviourA>
```

However, this requires that the `Content` type explicitly knows about all behaviour types, which is not possible if `Content` is exported as an api in a crate.

Ideally `Content` would have an api like:

```
fn behaviour<T>(&self) -> Option<T> where T: Any;
```

Which could be invoked at runtime as:

```
match content_item.behaviour::<&BehaviourA>() {
  Some(x) => { ... },
  None => {}
}
```

However, I cannot find any way to implement this function.

My best attempt reads like this:

```
fn behaviour<T>(&self) -> Option<T> where T: Any {
  let own_type = TypeId::of::<T>();
  if own_type == TypeId::of::<Behaviour>() { return Some(self as T); }
  return None;
}
```

But this results in:

```
src/foo.rs:21:62: 21:71 error: non-scalar cast: `&interface::test::Foo` as `T`
src/foo.rs:21       if own_type == TypeId::of::<Behaviour>() { return Some(self as T); }
```

I appreciate there is no way to introspect a list of traits on an object at runtime, but here I'm explicitly casting to a known type in the implementation; it's simply that the bound T is not always satisfied.

Is there any way of doing this at all, even unsafely?

An example playpen showing the error is here: http://is.gd/fZNFA8

(NB. I have seen [Can you restrict a generic to T where T is a trait implemented by Self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845351/can-you-restrict-a-generic-to-t-where-t-is-a-trait-implemented-by-self), but my question is different; in a nutshell, is there any way, even unsafely to generate a trait reference at runtime?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that traits aren't types.  When you say `&BehaviourA`, you're not referring to the trait, you're referring to the *object-safe type* which is *derived* from the trait.  What you need to do is tell Rust that `T` isn't a type, but a trait.

Tragically, as of 1.6, there's still no way of doing this.

The only way I know of to make something like this work is explicitly, *a-la* COM: you need a base interface that allows you to ask "cast to a reference to `X`", then implement that on each concrete type for all supported `X`.

If you're willing to dip into unsafe, messy code, you can get something *vaguely* like what you want with some macros ([playpen](http://is.gd/Bp3zvb)):

```rust
// Requires nightly compiler, since it depends on implementation details.
#![feature(raw)]

use std::any::TypeId;
use std::mem::transmute;
use std::raw::TraitObject;

macro_rules! qi {
    ($e:expr, $t:ty) => {
        unsafe {
            let iid = TypeId::of::<$t>();
            let ptr = &$e;
            match ptr.query_interface(&iid) {
                Some(to) => {
                    let tmp: &$t = transmute(to);
                    Some(tmp)
                },
                None => None,
            }
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! impl_unknown_for {
    ($base:ty: $($ints:ty),*) => {
        unsafe impl Unknown for $base {
            fn query_interface(&self, iid: &TypeId) -> Option<TraitObject> {
                unsafe {
                    $(
                        if *iid == TypeId::of::<$ints>() {
                            let to = transmute::<&$ints, _>(self);
                            return Some(to);
                        }
                    )*
                    None
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

unsafe trait Unknown {
    fn query_interface(&self, iid: &TypeId) -> Option<TraitObject>;
}

trait BehaviourA { fn a(&self); }
trait BehaviourB { fn b(&self); }
trait BehaviourC { fn c(&self); }

struct Thingy;

impl_unknown_for!(Thingy: BehaviourA, BehaviourC);

impl BehaviourA for Thingy {
    fn a(&self) { println!("Thingy::a"); }
}

impl BehaviourC for Thingy {
    fn c(&self) { println!("Thingy::c"); }
}

fn main() {
    let obj: Box<Unknown> = Box::new(Thingy);
    if let Some(ba) = qi!(obj, BehaviourA) { ba.a(); }
    if let Some(bb) = qi!(obj, BehaviourB) { bb.b(); }
    if let Some(bc) = qi!(obj, BehaviourC) { bc.c(); }
}
```